# Error: Invalid character in header content ["jwt_token"]

Tags: api, postman

I was following this guide https://helpx.adobe.com/marketing-cloud-core/kb/adobe-io-authentication-step-by-step.html on adobe api.

After converting the v1 api call to v2 exchangeJwt.json in the guide I imported it as instructed added the appropriate keys and values hit send. It returned the error

[image]

I'm pretty sure I followed the instructions so I am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: What do your request headers look like? Do you have extra characters (space etc) in the header name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, just put `jwt_token` in body `form-data`, not `["jwt_token"]` in `header`

[image]

Comment: thanks didn't notice I accidentally pasted it on the header initially